# Is there a way to add timeout in axios.all?

Tags: javascript, axios

We can add timeout in each request in config object like below in each request

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Is there a way to add this timeout in `axios.all()` request where there are multiple request and I want timeout for all of them to complete in say 10 seconds. Currently I put timeout in each request. Is there a way to put the timeout for all the request at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way would be to use simple JavaScript timeout function along with the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cancel

For eg:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosCancel from 'axios-cancel';

axiosCancel(axios, {
  debug: false // default
});

axios.all..

    setTimeout(()=>{
          axios.cancelAll();
    },3000) //will cancel all axios requests after 3 seconds
```

Comment: Nice workaround but is there a` cancelAll()` function in axios ? I can't find it.

Comment: Use axios-cancel npm package along with axios. I have added the link in the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer